# Parameter-estimation by (B)IC minimization

Tags: generalized-linear-model, estimation, maximum-likelihood, nonparametric, optimization

Suppose I want to estimate the parameters of a penalized Poisson-model $\mathbb{\lambda}_{\mathbb{\rho}} = \log(\mathbf{X}\mathbb{\beta}_{\mathbb{\rho}})$, where the columns of the matrix $\mathbf{X}$ are the basis of a B-spline function and $\mathbb{\beta}$ some weighting vector subject to the penalization of $\mathbb{\rho}$.

For a known vector of $\mathbb{\rho}$, $\mathbb{\beta}$ is usually estimated by maximizing the penalized log-likelihood $\ell(\mathbb{\beta},\mathbb{\rho}) = \ell(\mathbb{\beta}) - \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{\rho}\mathbb{\beta}^T\mathbf{S}\mathbb{\beta}$ with respect to $\mathbb{\beta}$, where $\mathbf{S}$ corresponds to a penalty-matrix of full column rank.

In order to estimate $\mathbb{\rho}$, I minimize 
 $BIC(\mathbb{\beta},\mathbb{\rho}) = -\ell(\mathbb{\beta},\mathbb{\rho}) + \log(n)df(\mathbb{\beta},\mathbb{\rho})$, where n is the sample-size and $df(\mathbb{\beta},\mathbb{\rho})$ a function that estimates the degrees of freedom.

If $\ell(\mathbb{\beta},\mathbb{\rho})$ is convex in $\mathbb{\beta}$ and $BIC(\mathbb{\beta},\mathbb{\rho})$ in $\mathbb{\rho}$, than there exists a unique Nash-equilibrium that grantees the unique solution ($\widehat{\mathbb{\beta}}, \widehat{\mathbb{\rho}}$).

The optimization now goes as follows:

1. Set j = 1.
2. Maximize $\ell(\mathbb{\beta},\mathbb{\rho})$ (or minimize by multiplication of -1) for $\mathbb{\rho} = \widehat{\mathbb{\rho}}_j$, and derive $\widehat{\mathbb{\beta}}_j$.
3. Take $\widehat{\mathbb{\beta}}_j$ from step 1 to update the value of $\mathbb{\rho}_j$ by minimizing $BIC(\mathbb{\beta}_j,\mathbb{\rho})$.

Repeating (2,3) until convergence, as measured by some criteria (for instance the norm of the BIC-gradient) to retrieve the final estimates of ($\widehat{\mathbb{\beta}}, \widehat{\mathbb{\rho}}$).

The optimization scheme crucially depends on the convexity of the functions, I wonder if this has been shown to be true for the BIC?

For the log-likelihood and the canonical exponential families: in their natural parametrization, the parameter space is convex and the log-likelihood is concave (see, e.g. Thm 1.6.3 in Bickel & Doksum's Mathematical Statistics, Volume 1. Under some mild technical conditions, i.e., that $\mathbf{X}$ has "full rank", or equivalently, that the natural parameter by identifiable, the log-likelihood function is strictly concave (Corollary 1.6.2 in the same reference).

Comment: What specifically is the "this" in "this has been shown to be true for the BIC, if the canonical link is taken"?

Comment: I provided some reference at the bottom, which was initially posted by DavidR: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16769/13636 .