# Is the class of models for which the MLE exists also the one for which flat priors are permissible?

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, identifiability, improper-prior

By "permissible" (for lack of a better term) I mean models which despite of a "flat" (improper) prior (i.e., $\int_{\Theta} p(\theta) d \theta = + \infty$) nevertheless produce a proper posterior (i.e., $\int_{\Theta} p(\theta|\mathbf{x}) d \theta = 1$). Under those circumstances, the likelihood does the heavy lifting, and [the MAP will equal the MLE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/140168).

But there are of course many models whose [likelihood does not have a (unique) maximum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/16758) and usually require some additional constraints to be estimable. So intuition says that for those models, a flat prior would produce an improper posterior. Is that the case, and if not, what characterizes the exceptions?

EDIT: Having looked through the archives some more, I noticed that [a related questions was answered here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/97768).

Answer (score 5):

No, these are somewhat different problems.  If you have an improper flat prior and you don't have a unique MLE, you will often not have a unique posterior mode, so neither MLE nor MAP estimation will be useful without some additional thought/constraints.  But you can easily have a proper posterior.

Some examples:

- Mixture models, where there is non-identifiability because of relabelling. There will still be relabelling in the posterior, but the posterior will be proper as long as the mixing probabilities are bounded away from zero
- 'Flat' or nearly flat regions in the likelihood: if you have $2\times 2$ table where you only observe the margins, the odds ratio is non-identifiable and the likelihood is nearly flat over some range of values. Given a flat prior, you'd get a flat posterior over that range. However, the flat range will typically be bounded so that the posterior is proper.
- it's quite possible to have non-identifiability with bounded parameter spaces, so even a flat posterior would be proper.  Suppose $Y\sim Binomial(1,p_1)$ and you have a flat prior over $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ for $(p_1,p_2)$. The posterior for $p_2$ (about which you *have no data*) will still be flat, but it will not be improper.

Conversely, you can get an improper posterior without non-identifiability.  Hobert and Casella discuss this for linear mixed models [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2291572). They don't explicitly use flat priors, but their improper priors could be regarded as flat for some transformed parameter.

One situation where you can get an improper posterior from non-identifiability is when the likelihood is flat on a unbounded subspace of the parameter space.  Suppose you have a model $Y\sim N(\alpha+\beta,1)$.  The data only tell you about $\alpha+\beta$ and your posterior for $\alpha-\beta$ will be flat if the prior is flat.

Comment: For mixtures, you can use only a special category of improper priors. See, e.g., our paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.01178

Comment: It seems I was imprecise with the question. I understand not every posterior will have a unique mode. My main question was under which conditions we can guarantee a proper posterior despite the prior being improper; and to what extend these conditions are similar to the [regularity conditions on the likelihood function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Regularity_conditions) in MLE.

Comment: And the answer was that the conditions have almost nothing to do with the regularity conditions for the MLE.

Comment: I see. There must be _some_ conditions though, right? Is there anything to be added to [the answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/97790)?

Answer (score 3):

If the prior is uniform then

$$f(\theta|x) \propto \frac{\mathcal{L}(\theta,x)}{\int_{\theta \in \Theta} \mathcal{L}(\theta,x) d\theta}$$

And this is a proper distribution when the integral of the likelihood function in the denominator is finite.

An simple example where this is not gonna work is when for a particular observation $x$ the likelihood is above some finite value in an infinite range of the parameters.  For example consider Poisson distribution $X \sim Poisson(\lambda=1/\theta)$ and the observation $x=0$, then the likelihood is equal to $\mathcal{L}(\theta,0) = e^{-1/\theta}$ then we need to compute the integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-1/\theta} d\theta$ which diverges and has no finite value.